# Problema variable sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Estoy haciendo una app en la que intento que al producirse un evento, guarde la fecha y la hora en determinado formato y luego éstas puedan ser recuperadas. Android Studio me dice

> "cannot find symbol"

como que no encuentra las variables. Las variables las defino más adelante pero por la estructura del programa necesito que las lea no solo más adelante donde las defino, sino también antes dentro de un `public void`. Son las variables fechamostrar y horamostrar las que no me puede leer en el primer public void.

ahí va el código:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16.0f));
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if( hasLocation(this) ) {
            float latitude = getLastLatitude(this);
            float longitude = getLastLongitude(this);
            float accuracy = getLastAccuracy(this);
            String street = getLastStreet(this);
            locationTextView.setText("Aparcaste en: ("+latitude+","+longitude+")");
            locationTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : btAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
                if (device.getAddress().equals(carBtAddress)) {
                    {
                                            }
                }
            }
            if( street==null || street.length()==0 ) {
                if(Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                    Location last = new Location("be.ndusart");
                    last.setLatitude(latitude);
                    last.setLongitude(longitude);
                    (new GetAddressTask()).execute(last);

                }
            } else
                locationTextView.setText("Aparcaste en: " + street +" "+fechamostrar+ " " +horamostrar);
.
.
.
.


@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Date d=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat fecc=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String fechacComplString = fecc.format(d);
            SimpleDateFormat ho=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
            String horaString = ho.format(d);
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("hora", horaString);
            editor.putString("fecha", fechacComplString);
            editor.commit();
            String fechamostrar = preferences.getString("fecha","01-01-2017");
            String horamostrar = preferences.getString("hora","01-01-2017");
            if( result != null && result.length() > 0 ) {
                locationTextView.setText("Aparcaste en: "+result+ " "+fechamostrar+ " " +horamostrar);
            }
```

Comment: en donde tira el error? podrías copiar el mensaje completo?

Comment: lo tira en esta línea: locationTextView.setText("Aparcaste en: " + street +" "+fechamostrar+ " " +horamostrar);
.pone en rojo fechamostrar y horamostrar, y al mirar que error es, dice: "cannot find symbol fechamostrar" y en horamostrar lo mismo: "cannot find symbol horamostrar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes definir las variables   fechamostrar y horamostrar, como variables de clase, no dentro del método:

```
private String fechamostrar;
private String horamostrar;
```

y posteriormente asignar el valor dentro de `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        ...
        ...
        fechamostrar = preferences.getString("fecha","01-01-2017");
        horamostrar = preferences.getString("hora","01-01-2017");
         ...
         ...

        }
```

De esta forma no tendrías el problema que comentas en la linea de código:

```
locationTextView.setText("Aparcaste en: " + street +" "+fechamostrar+ " " +horamostrar);
```

Comment: Lo he hecho y deja construir y hacer la apk, pero en la app las variables devuelven null en  public void onMapReady. Me explico: las lee en onPostExecute, que aunque está después de "on MapReady", se ejecuta antes. Lo que ocurre resumiendo es esto: las variables aparecen 2 veces.La primera que aparece cronológicamente es llamada después en la app, y en esta es donde da null aunque las haya definido como variable de clase. Si pongo el Shared Preferences  dentro del primer método, tengo lo mismo, en el segundo da null. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Bueno entonces el problema que indicas en tu pregunta esta resuelto. En cuanto al problema que mencionas debes asegurar obter antes los valores, si es posible en otra Activity qnterior